# Separating tags with a semicolon

Tags: php, tags

I have tags that separated by `;` in MySQL database and they are all in one field.

so whenever I try to load the field. the data will be displayed like this :

`tag1 ; tag2 ; tag3`

What I want to do, is to add url to every tag. basically I want to display it like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com/tag1">tag1</a> 
<a href="http://example.com/tag2">tag2</a>  
<a href="http://example.com/tag3">tag3</a>
```

I was thinking to use `str_replace` to replace the `;` with `</a>` but how do I do the beginning of each tag!

Is there a code that does that better than `str_replace`?

Comment: I'd recommend storing tags as a JSON array in the database. That way you can simply `json_decode()` the tags into a nice array, ready for a `foreach` loop.

Comment: Alfo, the only time I see that as "nicer" than `;` is if you want to store semi-colons in the field. Your solution is *even worse* than the current storage because it goes from *hard* querying to *impossible*.

Comment: @Alfo JSON is a HUGE waste of space. Yes it is good for storing data, but its like XML if used for storing data. In the meantime, lets all use XML

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$tags = "tag1 ; tag2 ; tag3";
$t = explode(";",$tags);
$string = '';
foreach($t as $value) {
   $value = trim($value);
   $string .= "<a href='http://example.com/$value'>$value</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I have used this code and that is what I needed exactly.

Answer (score 8):

You may "cheat" and just [explode](http://php.net/explode) on `;` and [loop](http://php.net/foreach) through the resulting array.

---

This is **almost never** the right approach though! You should always strive to [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) your database (and if you don't you should know *exactly why* you choose not to). As it currently stands your table is not even adhering to the first normal form, which states that you should have only atomic data in each field. The reason this is a bad idea is because you will have a hard time querying the table (for example getting all rows with a certain tag).

What you *should* do is create a separate table for the tags, containing two fields: `postid` (from the table you already have) and `tag`. Then use a `JOIN` operation to join them together.

Comment: the table has been created 2 years ago. and it has over 10000 raws. it will take to much time for one person to edit it and separate it into two tables. so, I was looking for a code that solve the problem "for now". 

Thank you though. your information, and your answer is the best of them all.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = "tag1 ; tag2 ; tag3";
$tags = explode(" ; ", $string);
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
  echo '<a href="http://example.com/'. $tag .'">' . $tag .'</a>';
}
```